# Stop reload () after a certain scroll

Tags: java, android

With this code, as I while scrolling, say 10%, disable web.reload (); And for one, as I variable String url of shouldOverrideUrlLoading endure beyond the example as above in a variable String XYvariable.

```
package ru.myapplication;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    TextView TEXT;

    String XYvariable;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final WebView web = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
        web.loadUrl("http://example.com/string.html");
        web.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

        new Timer().schedule(new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                web.reload();
            }
        }, 1000, 1000);



        web.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                String Cur = (String) url.substring(23);
                String Link = (String) url.substring(16,23);
                String XY = (String) url; // Post varriable up in string XYvariable
                setContentView(R.layout.vot);
                TEXT = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
                switch (Link){
                    case "id_user":
                        TEXT.setText(Cur+" / user");
                        break;
                    case "id_mess":
                        TEXT.setText(Cur + " / messages");
                        break;
                }

                return true;
            }
        });
    }
    public boolean  onCreateOptionsMenu (Menu menu){
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);

        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }
}
```

> XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="ru.MainActivity">

    <WebView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/webView"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />



</RelativeLayout>
```

In advance thank you all, very much! ))